# Error 91 in VBA using simple classes

Tags: vba, excel, editor

```
Dim newCIS As CIS
Dim newString As String

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    newString = "lol"
    newCIS.ContactName = newString
    UserForm1.Label1.Caption = newCIS.ContactName
End Sub
```

I run into an Error 91 on line 6. Here is the CIS class:

```
Private strContactName As String

Property Let ContactName(name As String)
    Set strContactName = name
End Property

Property Get ContactName() As String
    Set ContactName = strContactName
End Property
```

I've also tried using a set function instead of property let, but that also leads to an error 91. Is there some crucial knowledge about object oriented programming in vba that I'm missing?

Comment: It might be worth noting, that you don't need to `Set` the class properties. `ContactName = strContactName` will do the job.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to create a new instance of the class:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    newString = "lol"
    Set newCIS = New CIS
    newCIS.ContactName = newString
    UserForm1.Label1.Caption = newCIS.ContactName
End Sub
```

Comment: That did it! Could you give me some insight on why Dim newCIS as CIS doesn't create an instance of the class? Thanks so much!

Comment: Because that only *declares* an object variable. It doesn't initialize it. That's what the `New`  keyword is for.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!